# Pattern matching operator/constructor in expression

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I'm trying to write a function that simplifies expressions by identifying parts of it that will evaluate to zero, so that n*0 -> 0 and n+0 -> n etc.

```
elimiZeros :: Exp -> Exp
```

The data type is:

```
data Exp = Num Int
     | Add Exp Exp
     | Sub Exp Exp
     | Mult Exp Exp
     | Div Exp Exp
     | Power Exp Exp
     | Neg Exp
     deriving Show
```

To avoid having to pattern match each operator by themselves, I tried matching several at the same time, however I get a compiler error: "Parse error in pattern: a":

```
elimiZeros :: Exp -> Exp
elimiZeros (Num n) = (Num n)
elimiZeros (a b c) = 
  if c == (Num 0)
    then case a of
      Add -> elimiZeros b
      Sub -> elimiZeros b
      Mult -> (Num 0)
  else if b == (Num 0)
    then case a of
      Add -> elimiZeros c
      Sub -> elimiZeros c
      -- etc, not finished
  else (a b c)
```

Isn't it possible to pattern match with this syntax?

Edit: Thank you for the clarifying responses!

Comment: This isn't how pattern matching works - you can only do it against constructors, and can't, as you see here, use a variable to stand for the constructor. Perhaps there's a language extension which allows this, if there is I'm not aware of it. But I don't see that you actually write less code doing it the way you want - and I find it less readable compared to the standard way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haskell does not allow patterns like

```
f (a b c) = ...
```

To see why, consider this type:

```
data T = A Int Int | B Bool Bool

f :: T -> ...
f (a b c) = ...
```

If that were allowed, what would be the type of `b` and `c`? Well, it could be `Int` or `Bool`, we can't know for sure. So, in general, `(a b c)` patterns are forbidden, requiring that a pattern must start with an explicit constructor (unless the pattern is just a variable, of course).

In your code, you can try using multiple equations

```
elimiZeros (Add b (Num 0)) = ...
elimiZeros (Add b c      ) = ...
...
```

avoiding most of your `if`s.

Comment: it *could* be ``(`Int` or `Bool`)``. But then what would that `or` be?... in what type system?... the first thing that must be told about Haskell's is that it wants its types known *in full* upfront. that is quite hard to get to outsiders, esp. coming from dynamic languages, esp. that it is never actually *said.* (at least I didn't see it).

Comment: @WillNess Indeed. Some type systems allow "union types" like `Int or Bool`, but they are quite complex to use (in type checking / type inference). In Haskell, there's no real need to use that. AFAIK, `mypy` does use union types, with some success, but there type inference is (overall) simpler than in Haskell.

Answer (score 4):

Can't do that. Consider this instead:

```
data Operator = Add | Sub | Mult | Div | Power
data Exp = Num Int | Neg Exp | Bin Operator Exp Exp
```

Now you can write something very similar to what you tried:

```
elimiZeros (Bin a b c) = ...
```